# My travis-ci build runs forever after the app ran successfully

Tags: python-3.x, travis-ci

I have a small python app and I want to make sure it starts without any problems when someone makes a new github pull request/commit.

Now the problem is that once I run the app it runs forever because everything is working without any problems.

Is there a way to close the build with status 0 after 2 minutes since the build?

Here is my .travis.yml file

```
python:
  - "3.7-dev"

install:
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  - pip3 install pytest

before_script:
  - chmod +x deploy.sh
  - chmod +x changelog.sh



branches:
  only:
    - travis-test

script:
  - python3 -m tg_companion

after_success:
  ./deploy.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to wrap the start of your app in a script which kills it after a certain amount of time.

In `travis.yml` set:

```
script:
  - bash timeout.sh
```

Then create a `timeout.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run your app in the background
python3 -m tg_companion &

# Store it's Process ID
bg_pid=$!

# sleep for X seconds
sleep 120

# Kill the python process
kill $bg_pid

# Optionally exit true to prevent travis seeing this as an error
exit 0
```

The alternative would be to modify your module to notice when it is being run in test mode, and kill itself after a timeout - possibly a command-line flag, or looking at the environment for e.g. `TRAVIS=true` or `CI=true`

Comment: Thanks it worked ^^ I just used the environment after importing all the modules so If there's any errors it will send a failure

Answer (score 0):

Create another python file test.py with the following code.

```
import tg_companion
```

Instead of running tg_companion, run test. i.e.-`python3 -m test`
(In the script of .travis.yml)